# Closing an app not sending WM_QUIT message?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Having such a simple Win32 app:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    ...
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"Learn to Program Windows", WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER, 0, 0, 190, 110, nHwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd != NULL) {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
            
        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)                 {
                swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_QUIT (main)\n"));
                OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {

        case WM_DESTROY:
            swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_DESTROY\n"));
            OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_CLOSE\n"));
            OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return 0;

        case WM_QUIT:
            swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_QUIT\n"));
            OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
            Example_DrawImage9(hdc);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When i do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close it i get WM_CLOSE, WM_DESTROY but NOT WM_QUIT? Why don't I get the WM_QUIT message?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage

Comment: WM_QUIT makes GetMessage() return 0.  So you'll never see it.

Comment: I think it was inappropriate for a third party to remove the C++ tag, as that is probably the language that is being used. By default, Windows Desktop Applications created in Microsoft Visual Studio are C++ files, even if they use an API that resembles C more than C++. Therefore, in my opinion, the question was correctly tagged by OP. For this reason, I have reverted the edit.

Comment: I am the one who removed the tag. I do that often when the question is really not related to C++ features. When someone adds the C++ tag and the question is not really about C++ language features, the C++ people downvote the question and pretty soon it is closed. The correct tags for this would be winapi and maybe windows. The post had nothing to do with C++ language features. However, I am not going to edit this post again.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson: Please don't do that.  The language tag is appropriate on a question even if the question doesn't involve language peculiarities (and often whether peculiarities are involved is not known up-front).  C++ experts are perfectly able to add `winapi` to their ignored tags if they don't want questions about C++ programs using the Windows API.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson: If I applied your policy, then most questions with both a "C" and "POSIX" tag woud have to have their "C" tag removed. That seems quite extreme to me. Do you happen to have any links to meta discussions which would corroborate that your policy is community consensus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-quit:

> The WM_QUIT message is not associated with a window and therefore will
> never be received through a window's window procedure. It is retrieved
> only by the GetMessage or PeekMessage functions.
>
> Do not post the WM_QUIT message using the PostMessage function; use
> PostQuitMessage.

=== Portion after this was added after answer accepted for further clarification ===

As others have noted, there are sort of two things going on in the original code submitted. In the message map, there is a switch case entry for WM_QUIT. The documentation I quoted shows that the message is not for windows and so the case statement will never get processed.

However, there is another issue going on. Look at the message pumping:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);

    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)                 {
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_QUIT (main)\n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
    }
}
```

When `GetMessage()` is called and the WM_QUIT message is the message retrieved in the queue, then the return value from `GetMessage()` will be zero and so it will immediately exit the while loop.

This is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage

> If the function retrieves a message other than WM_QUIT, the return
> value is nonzero.
>
> If the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is
> zero.

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the OP's question.  The code is already using `PostQuitMessage()`, and is not trying to process `WM_QUIT` in the window procedure.  This answer does not address the fact that the code's message loop will never see `WM_QUIT` due to the loop breaking when `GetMessage()` returns 0 when `WM_QUIT` is retreived. THAT is the real answer.